# Authenticate with Atmosphere + Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard, atmosphere

Hi I am looking for a way to authenticate users when they make WebSocket connection and simply if they are not authenticated close the connection. I am using Dropwizard framework and Atmosphere for the WebSocket connections. [Here](https://github.com/stakkTraze/dropwizard-atmosphere) is the example that I use. 
It would be great if I could use '@Auth' annotation provided by Dropwizard for authentication when the connection is establishing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you exposing this? Is it through a javascript frontend?

You are using the servlet based approach as described in your link and here: https://cvwjensen.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/websockets-in-dropwizard/, and not the jersey atmosphere extension?

If you are using the servlet based approach would recommend using a token-based approach putting the token in the http header an then access this header in the @Ready handler method, like this:

```
@Ready
public String onReady(final AtmosphereResource resource) {
    String AuthHeader = resource.getRequest().getHeader("Authorization");

    ...DO AUTH HERE

    logger.info("Resource {} connected ", resource.uuid());
    return "Connect " + resource.uuid();
}
```

Then, you could also easily close the connection if auth fails. However, depending on your client side implementation, you might want to think about this. If the client auto-reconnects on close, you have a scenario of constant closing and opening of sockets that may cause a resource drain. You could, if auth is not successful, store a private variable that states whether or not this instance is authenticated and just drop sending any messages to or process any messages from it. That would also be a "obscure" way of letting an attacker know that auth failed, it simply is in a limbo state; connected, but not failed or closed. Just not receiving any data. But again, this is specific to your implementation.

Jwt auth is an option, check this out: https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt. I have, although not made it public, ported this implementation to dropwizard 0.8rc3-SNAPSHOT. If you need this, please let me know and I can post it to github.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I ended up adding the access token to the header. Also like you said, before closing the connection I let the client know why the connection is being closed.